# Align google Captcha box centally on contact form 7

Tags: css, wordpress, recaptcha, captcha, contact-form-7

I'm trying to add a captcha V2 box onto my contact form but, I am not able to align it centrally and it always aligns to the left.

It appears the iframe is adding a div style with width and height set, if i set this to auto in inspector (element.style) it removes the left alignment but adding a class CSS rule in the customiser doesn't seem to make any difference even if i make it !important, nether does wrapping a div around the short code in the contact from builder so I'm a little stuck

https://bseclients.co.uk/drinksnow/index.php/wedding-bar-hire/

Comment: Questions seeking code help must include the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself**  preferably in a **Stack Snippet**. Although you have provided a link, if it was to become invalid, your question would be of no value to other future SO users with the same problem. See [**Something in my website/example doesn't work can I just paste a link**](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/254428/something-in-my-web-site-or-project-doesnt-work-can-i-just-paste-a-link-to-it).

Comment: .wpcf7-form-control-wrap > div > div {text-align:center; margin:0 auto;} add this code in your stylesheet

Comment: You need to just add this css .wpcf7-form-control-wrap .g-recaptcha>div {
    display: block;
    margin: 0 auto;
}

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Put this CSS in the File.

```
.g-recaptcha > div{margin: 0 auto;}
```